# How to measure code coverage in a webapp through unit and functional tests

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, code-coverage, bdd, functional-testing

I'm a little bit stuck with a task that I have been researching. It's about code coverage in a react webapp.

I implemented a few unit tests using jest + enzyme. also some functional test, using cucumber to get gherkin features and puppeteer for browser automation.

I have able to get the coverage from the code built by webpack and served on my localhost using puppeteer and istanbul through functional tests. Also, I get code coverage from unit test using jest (btw, it include istanbul to do that).

The problem is: I feel those are two diferents metrics, because I test components with jest + enzyme file by file, and in the other hand, I have code coverage from puppeteer that actually is a single built js file.

The goal should be get code coverage from unit tests and functional tests.

So, my questions are:

- has sense, mesure the code coverage on unit tests and functional tests?
- has sense, merge code coverage from unit tests and functional tests? and if has sense how to do that?
- what is the best aproach to get code coverage from a webapp?

Comment: Cross posted: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/code-coverage-in-react-webapp

Answer (score 0):

Overall your approach to measuring, recording and reporting code coverage will be tailored to your use case. This means that there aren't clear right or wrong answers to your question. I am going to try to give you ideas that help you decide the best approach for you and your team.

I would start by asking yourself why are we measuring code coverage? I.E. what is the change in how the team operates that you are trying to create? I will come back to this question while answering your specific questions.

It is worth at this point making sure that code coverage will encourage the behavior you are looking for. For more on this look at this [paper](https://www.ou.edu/russell/UGcomp/Kerr.pdf). I have tried to tackle this question in a recent [blog post](https://www.diffblue.com/blog/2019/3/27/how-and-why-to-set-code-coverage-targets-breaking-the-arbitrary-goal-trend).

I am making a few assumptions here about the layout of the team that you are working in so please forgive me if the assumptions are wrong.

`measure the code coverage on unit tests and functional tests?`

If you want to encourage the team to write tests, or, automate a significant portion of testing then yes it is appropriate to measure code coverage as it is a great measure of whether people are adding tests at the same rate as the code is changing.

`merge code coverage from unit tests and functional tests?`

Let's consider the example where you want to encourage developers to write more unit tests. In this case, I would say no, don't merge coverage. The desired behavior change is for the developers to write more tests, therefore, you don't want to mask their lack of testing by reporting a metric that includes functional tests from a QA team.

However, if you are considering the Software Engineering team and would like more testing from the whole team (Developers and QA) then absolutely combine the coverage numbers and report the total coverage.

`if has sense how to do that?`

There are plenty of tools out there that will allow you to combine coverage information from multiple runs. One of my favorites (assuming you can use cloud-based services) is [CodeCov](https://codecov.io). This is a great way of visualizing your code coverage with minimal setup effort.

`what is the best approach to get code coverage from a webapp?`

I am going to leave this one for someone who understands in more detail than I do the technologies that you are using.